# Why are dead keys not working with some letters in AutoHotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, globalization, keyboard-hook, dead-key

In an AutoHotkey script, why do dead keys not work with some letters?
As an example, when running AutoHotkey with the following script:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
EndKeys = {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}

<^>!`::
Input, SingleKey, L1, EndKeys
IfInString,SingleKey,a
Send,{U+00E0} ;à
IfInString,SingleKey,e
Send,{U+00E8} ;è
return
return
```

then pressing the combination of 
Alt-Gr & Grave, followed by an 'a', i get à, OK, but 
Alt-Gr & Grave, followed by an 'e' does NOT produce è.

The issue is not related to grave (`), the same thing happens with any other dead keys (like circumflex, acute, macron etc.)

In my particular case, the letters not working are: e y s d k n. Could it have something to do with the keyboard layout? (I am using a UK English). Any ways of approaching the issue to ensure the dead keys will work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my particular case, the letters not working are: e y s d k n

Try reorganizing these letters. I find this very hillarious indeed. Please insert any expression of laughter yourself, for it would not be welcomed on stackoverflow if I did.

You forgot to include your `%`'s. It should be

```
Input, SingleKey, L1, %EndKeys%
```

Otherwise, only `e`, `n`, `d`, `k`, `y`, `s` will be recognized as EndKeys

Comment: You were absolutely correct!! :D wow, I was already going crazy with this heheh